# Segmentation Fault when working with argv C++

Tags: c++

I have until now:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  std::vector<std::string> args;

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      args.push_back({ argv[i] });
  }
  std::string dateString = args[1];

return 0;
}
```

and I get `Segmentation Fault` on line: `std::string dateString = args[1];`

What I want to do is to use something like: `./myalgorithm.cpp 2022-09-01` where `2022-09-01` is a date. Then, I want to get to this date via `argv[1]`, save it to a `std::string variable` and then do some computation with each value from the date( 2022, 09 and 01).

I was thinking to save this date to a `string` and then with the use of `string.substr(...)` to save into `int variables` the numbers from the date:

```
int year = stoi(mystring.substr(0,4));
int month = stoi(mystring.substr(6,2));
int day = stoi(mystring.substr(9,2));
```

EDIT:
I edited my code and it works:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  std::vector<std::string> args;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      args.push_back({ argv[i] });
  }

  for (auto dateString: args) {
      double year = stoi(dateString.substr(0,4));
      double month = stoi(dateString.substr(5,2));
      double day = stoi(dateString.substr(8,2));
      std::cout << year << std::endl;
      std::cout << month << std::endl;
      std::cout << day << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But I don't understand why do I need to write:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      args.push_back({ argv[i] });
  }
```

Instead of simply:

```
std::vector<std::string> args;
args.push_back({ argv[1] });
```

EDIT:

Corrected Code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  std::vector<std::string> args;
  if (argc > 1){
    args.push_back({ argv[1] });
  }
  for (auto dateString: args) {
      int year = stoi(dateString.substr(0,4));
      int month = stoi(dateString.substr(5,2));
      int day = stoi(dateString.substr(8,2));
      int gpsweek = GPSweek(year, month, day);
      printf("%d\n", gpsweek);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed in C++. If you supply one argument, its index is 0 and the index 1 is out-of-bounds

Comment: What if there's no `argv[1]`?

Comment: `std::string dateString = args[1];` should be `std::string dateString = args[0];` after you determine if there are enough arguments. `argc` could be 1.

Comment: `std::string dateString = args[1];` -- Change that to `std::string dateString = args.at(1);`.  The `std::out_of_range` exception you will get should be self-explanatory.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just `args.push_back({ argv[1] });` instead of the loop, but only if `argc > 1`. The loop essentially does the same thing, but it wouldn't be entered if no command line parameters were passed and `argc == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `./myalgorithm.cpp 2022-09-01`, what are `argc` and `argv`?

`argc` is count of arguments + program name.

`argv` is program name and these arguments.

So `argc` = 2 and `argv` = { myalgorithm.cpp, 2022-09-01 }

```cpp
  std::vector<std::string> args;

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      args.push_back({ argv[i] });
  }
```

After the code, the variable `args` is { "2022-09-01" } because you start from i = 1 but not 0.

C++ array (including std::vector) index starts from 0, so the first item has index being 0. If you try to take the second item with index = 1 then it is the array out of bounds. It is Undefined Behavior in C++ and Segmentation Fault is one of the outcomes.

Use `args[0]` to take the first item - "2022-09-01".

The range based `for` uses iterators which start from index = 0 for std::vector, therefore your correct code works.